# Listing Records with Zero-Length Field in Sub-Form

Tags: ms-access

I'm having a problem with a database I created in MS Access 2003.

There is a table (let's call it tblItems) with four fields: id, description, category, sub_category. The sub_category field is the only one which is not required and allows zero-length data.

I created a form based on this table (frmAddItems) which has two combo-boxes (cboCategory & cboSubCategory), a text box (txtDescription) and a sub-form (sbfExistingItems) which is supposed to list existing items based on what was selected in the two combo-boxes. This works perfectly as long as a sub-category is selected, but if there's no sub-category, sbfExistingItems is empty.

The Record Source for sbfExistingItems is: "SELECT tblItems.id, tblItems.description, tblItems.category, tblItems.sub_category FROM tblItems ORDER BY [description];"

frmAddItems and sbfExistingItems are linked as follows:

- Child Fields: category;sub_category
- Master Fields: cboCategory;cboSubCategory

The problem is presumably related to how Access handles zero-length data, but I don't know how to make it do what I want it to do. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Update**

As suggested by jhTuppeny, I have removed the child/master links on the subform and added the following code:

```
Private Sub txtDescription_GotFocus()

Dim sql As String

sql = "SELECT id, description, category, sub_category FROM tblItems"

If IsNull(Me!cboCategory) Or Me!cboCategory = "" Then
    ' leave recordsource unfiltered
ElseIf IsNull(Me!cboSubCategory) Or Me!cboSubCategory= "" Then
    sql = sql & " WHERE [category] = '" & Me!cboCategory & "'"
Else
    sql = sql & " WHERE [category] = '" & Me!cboCategory & "' AND [sub_category] = '" & Me!cboSubCategory & "'"
End If

sql = sql & " ORDER BY [description];"

Me!sbfExistingItems.Form.RecordSource = sql

End Sub
```

But now the subform acts like the child/master fields are linked on "id", listing only the current item.

I guess what it comes down to is that I need a way of altering the values of the child/master fields in the subform's form without the main form thinking that I'm trying to leave it while the required txtDescription field is empty.

Comment: I was just thinking that my next step would be to start learning about debugging. OK, so I added the line and clicked the Run button, but the only thing I got was a pop-up asking for a macro name. I clicked cancel, but nothing else happened. I do run a macro on opening the "master" form. Is that the name I should enter?

Comment: OK, got it. The query returns the expected result when there's a sub-category, but nothing when it's null (my original problem). From what I've read elsewhere, Access fails when comparing null = null.

Comment: This just made me realize that it's actually skipping the "ElseIf..." and going to the "Else..." when cboSubCategory is Null (or ""), which is exactly what I'm trying to avoid. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: OK, I fixed _that_ problem by checking for both Null and "", but I still have the problem with child/master fields being linked on "id". That must be the default when those fields are blank. Is there a way of checking for the subform's properties when debugging?

Comment: Yes, I did already do that. They are both blank in Design View. However, the subform _acts_ as if they are both set to "id", listing only the current item when txtDescription gets the focus (i.e., nothing when adding a new record; item description when viewing existing records).

Comment: I don't know how to do that. However, I just figured out how to have the debugger print the values of the child/master link properties, and they are indeed both being set to "id", presumably by default. Now I just  need to find a way of altering the values of the child/master fields in the subform's form without the main form thinking that I'm trying to leave it while the required txtDescription field is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you have specified a link between the sub category and the subform. When there is no sub category there is no link regardless of the category.

You need to create a query for your subform that will return records based on category and sub category but is not reliant on there being a sub category supplied. You can then set the recordsource of your subform using something like this;

```
Dim sql As String

sql = "SELECT tblItems.id, tblItems.description, tblItems.category, tblItems.sub_category "
sql = sql & "FROM tblItems "
If cboSubCategory.Value = "" Then
    sql = sql & "WHERE (category = cboCategory.Value) "
Else
    sql = sql & "WHERE (category = cboCategory.Value) AND (sub_category = cboSubCategory.Value)"
End If
sql = sql & "ORDER BY [description];"

sbfExistingItems.Form.RecordSource = sql
```

Comment: I had already tried that, but it didn't work.  Are you saying I should remove the links between the main form and the sub-form?

Comment: With the subform directly linked you'll not be able to take control of the situation in the way that you want. The approach I suggested will work but you'll need to add some code to this to get it to work in the way that you need - the example is just a rough outline.

Comment: I tried removing the master/child links and placing your suggested code in the GotFocus event of txtDescription, except that I used IsNull instead of = "". But that doesn't work either. In fact, Access doesn't seem to like the absence of the linked fields, and will sometimes reset them, linking id to id, which is not what I want.

Comment: I've tried several different variations on the above theme, with varying results (none of them right). My latest attempt is to alter LinkChildFields and LinkMasterFields instead of RecordSource, setting them either to category or category;sub_category. This is currently resulting in a run-time error 3314 (description cannot contain a Null value) as soon as txtDescription gets the focus??!!

Comment: This approach definitely works - I have used it any number of times in my databases. Make sure that your subform is not bound and doesn;t have any links set and then set the recordsource sql using the Category and SubCategory values. Use the AfterUpdate event on each of these combo boxes to refresh the recordsource.

Comment: Is there anything other than removing the child/master links that I need to do to "make sure that your subform is not bound"? See my update above.

Comment: You should remove the recordsource from your subform - you will be setting this in your code - also use the AfterUpdate events of the combo boxes to set the subform recordsource.

Comment: Removing the subform's recordsource causes an error ("The record source '' does not exist") when opening the main form and, if I continue, a run-time error 2467 (expression refers to an object that is closed or doesn't exist) when txtDescription gets the focus.

Comment: Also, if I remove the child/master links, Access re-sets them to "id", apparently by default.

Comment: I suggest that you start with an new form. Don't link it to a recordsource and add your subform to it. Then add a command button to verify that you can set the subform's datasource from the main form. Once you've done that you can add the other elements until your form is as you need it to work. If you step through the process you'll be able to figure out what isn't working. Also I think the text box that you're using to run the code is on the subform - I don't think this will work.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion to recreate the form. That did the trick. Apparently you can't successfully remove child/master links if they were generated when you added the subform.